# DS 160 form : Does being sent back to home country because of not having airport-transit visa count as deportation?

Tags: visas, usa, visa-refusals, legal, transit-visas

So, I am applying for a F1 visa to the US, and one of the questions in DS-160 asks :

"Have you ever been removed or deported from any country ?"

So couple of months ago, I was going to mexico city via a layover at Barcelona where I was required to have an airport transit visa. I didn't know about this rule and consequently I was sent back to my country (since I didn't have it ) .

My question is : Does this count as deportation/removal from a country? I am confused as to whether respond the DS 160 question above with a yes or a no .. Does anyone has had a similar experience before getting their US visa ? Can anyone please share their advice/opinion on this? Thanks.

Comment: Were you sent back *from Barcelona?*  Without an airport transit visa, you should not have been allowed to board a plane to Barcelona, which implies that you were sent back from somewhere else, earlier in your itinerary.

Comment: Without the more detailed information sought by @phoog in his comment above, this question is not answerable.

Comment: @phoog Barcelona has transit "border" control, at least at terminal 2

Comment: @Crazydre okay, that addresses a concern that I've expressed elsewhere about how a traveler might have been turned back at Barcelona assuming that the airline actually allowed the person on the plane, but I still find it unlikely that the person could have boarded the plane to Barcelona in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

No, you were **refused entry** into the Schengen Area due to the lack of a needed visa.

- You did not, officially, enter the Schengen Area

You cannot be **removed** or **deported** from a country when you, officially, never entered it.

These terms apply only in cases where you:

- you are illegally *within* (overstay or illegal entry) the country
- you are considered an **undesired alien** due to crimes commited *within* the country

The goal of the DS 160 question is to determin if you have committed some illegal activity in another country.

A **refused entry** is not considered an illegal activity and **not** being asked in the DS 160 question. The form itself uses the term **refused admission** elsewhere.

If you want to be very careful, then answer yes, but use the **refused entry** term with the reason why in the 'Explain' field of the form.

---

> Have you ever been **removed** or **deported** from any country ?

To understand how to answer such a question, you must understand, in a **legal sense**, what the used terms mean **or** what happened to you in the past (which may differ from jurasdiction to jurasdiction)

**removal**

- you are requested to leave a country by a specific date

  - issued by a local authority in a written form
  - you leave on your own account
- re-entry is generally prohibited for a specific period of time

  - which can be a cause for a **refused entry**

**deportation**

- you are detained and forced to leave a country

  - issued by a local authority in a written form
  - enforced by a border guard or immigration officer
- re-entry is generally prohibited for a specific period of time

  - which can be a cause for a **refused entry**

**refused entry** (or **refused admission**)

- conditions of entry not fullfill at **port of entry**

  - issued by a border guard or immigration officer at point of entry
  - you return immediately to your point of departure

    - the carrier that brought you there are mostly required to carry you back
- reasons can differ radically, depending on the reason

  - does not cause an automatic *flagging* of the traveler

Corresponding German law:

- AufenthG: [§6 - Visas](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0085)
- AufenthG: [§15 - Refusal of entry](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0218)
- AufenthG: [§57 - Removal, §58 - Deportation, §58a - Deportation order and §59 - Deportation warning](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p1084)

  - [Abschiebung (Recht)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abschiebung_(Recht)#Rechtslage)

    - reentry not allowed for a timeframe, including the transit area of Airports

> **Schengen Border Code ANNEX VI 2.1.3**:
>   ...
>   ; in particular checks in this area may be carried out on persons subject to an airport transit visa in order to check that they are in possession of such a visa.

For the Schengen Area, a **refusal of entry** will be documented in the passport as defined in the **Schengen Border Code, Annex V, Part A 1(b, d)**:

> (b) affix an entry stamp on the passport, cancelled by a cross in indelible black ink, and write opposite it on the right-hand side, also in indelible ink, **the letter(s) corresponding to the reason(s)** for refusing entry, the list of which is given on the abovementioned standard form for refusing entry;
>   (d) **record every refusal of entry** in a register or on a list stating the identity and nationality of the third-country national concerned, the references of the document authorising the third-country national to cross the border and the reason for, and date of, refusal of entry.

[image]

**Schengen Border Code, Annex V, Part B** contains a sample refusal form, where the meaning of the possible letters used can be seen.

- **C**: has no visa or residence permit
- **F**: overstayed 90/180 period

This should not be confused with the **invalidation of an exit stamp** (double crossing out through the euro symbol)

[image]

after a **refusal of entry** into the United Kingdom:

[image]

Comment: That was very helpful. Thank you so much. Can you please do me one more favour? Can you please let me know how sure you are of this matter, so that I can base my decision on this with lesser worry?

Comment: @Prashu For the Schengen Code, yes. If clicking no and entering something in 'Explain' is possible, enter *refused entry due to lack of transit visa...*. If you want to be very careful, then answer yes, but use **refused entry** term with the reason why.

Comment: It seems unlikely they were attempting to access the Schengen area for a flight to Mexico. More likely they are from a country that requires a visa to even transit Spain (eg, India)

Comment: @Doc you got it exactly right haha. But any suggestions on how to actually respond to the question in ds 160 , would you put yes or no ?

Comment: very informative answer!

Comment: @Prashu from where were you sent back?  Airport transit in the Schengen area does not involve entry into the Schengen area.  An airport transit visa does not allow its bearer to enter the Schengen area.  Someone attempting airport transit would not receive any Schengen passport stamp (whether successful or unsuccessful).  This answer is therefore incorrect when it says that you were "refused entry," because you never even *attempted* to enter. It is  nonetheless correct that you were neither removed nor deported.

Comment: @phoog Persons can be checked and if found without a needed visa can be **refused entry** with corresponding stamp. Schengen Border Code ANNEX VI 2.1.3: ... ; in particular **checks in this area may be carried out on persons subject to an airport transit visa** in order to check that they are in possession of such a visa.

Comment: @phoog Even before immigration control, person are within the **jurisdiction** of the Schengen country. So Article 14 of the Schengen Border Code can still be applied. Kindly revert your statement contradicting this and your overhasty downvote.

Comment: @MarkJohnson unless the airline makes a serious mistake, someone who needs an ATV but lacks one will never even enter Schengen airspace.  If the airline *does* make such a mistake, one of two things needs to happen before the border authorities in the transit airport become aware of it: either (1) they check the passenger manifest, notice that the passenger lacks a necessary ATV, and meet the passenger at the gate for the purpose of sending the passenger back, or (2) the passenger attempts to clear passport control....

Comment: ... It seems to me rather more likely that the passenger in this case was sent back from some airport other than Barcelona, because airlines don't generally board passengers who lack required visas for the flight's destination, but it's rather more common for them to board a passenger for the initial leg of a multiple flight itinerary when the missing documentation pertains to a subsequent leg (as may be seen from some of the questions here).  But since Prashu has not logged in to the site since I left my comment asking for clarification, we may never know for sure.

Comment: @phoog My impression is that that this is more of a theoretical question of the OP. In reality checks are probably seldon for your given reason. If, however, a check is done the due process would be a refused entry with 'C' as the given reason. Otherwise it wouldn't make any sense to check at all. So the statment that this is not possible is false.

Comment: Do you have any source for your "legal" definitions? According to USCIS and DHS (you can Google), since 1997, the USA prefers "removed" to "deported" and both terms are used interchangeably. Also, "voluntary departure," (which is also asked on the DS-160) which is when the USA asks you to leave is not considered either removal or deportation.

Comment: https://www.uscis.gov/tools/glossary?topic_id=d#alpha-listing "Before April 1997, deportation and exclusion were separate removal procedures. The Illegal Immigration Reform and Immigrant Responsibility Act of 1996 consolidated these procedures. After April 1, 1997, aliens in and admitted to the United States may be subject to removal based on deportability. Now called “removal,” this function is managed by U.S. Immigration and Customs Enforcement." Removal covers both deportability and inadmissibility. In some countries, deportation and removal are separate processes, but not in the USA.

Comment: @uberqe The legal definitions will be specific to the jurasdiction. My summary was based on the method used in the German law AufenthG: [§57 - Removal, §58 - Deportation, §58a - Deportation order and §59 - Deportation warning](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p1084). A summary can be found, with information about some other countries, in the German only wiki page: [Abschiebung (Recht)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abschiebung_(Recht)#Rechtslage), which also states that for the time reentry is not permitted (including the transit area of Airports).

Comment: @Mark Johnson The DS-160 is an American form. Only American definitions are valid. Neither of the two links you have given clarify the difference between being removed and deported--certainly not the way you describe. In fact, leaving on your own account after being asked to leave would be considered "voluntary departure" according to the links, not "removal."